# Laravel Routing with different amount of paramenters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, url-routing

I'm trying to accomplish the to control my function by the follwoing routes:

```
Route::get('tri/{uniquename}/photos/gallery/{pic}',  array( 'as' => 'sportevent', 'uses' =>  'SporteventController@thisevent'));
Route::get('tri/{uniquename}/{tab}/{filter}/',  array( 'as' => 'sportevent', 'uses' =>  'SporteventController@thisevent'));
Route::get('tri/{uniquename}/{tab}/',  array( 'as' => 'sportevent', 'uses' =>  'SporteventController@thisevent'));
```

I'm aware, that I could combine route 2 and 3 to

```
   Route::get('tri/{uniquename}/{tab}/{filter?}/',  array( 'as' => 'sportevent', 'uses' =>  'SporteventController@thisevent'));
```

but that's not really my problem here.

my function looks as follows (only the relevant code):

```
public function thisevent($uniquename, $tab="main", $filter="",$pic=""){

    if($pic!=""){
        $tab = "photos";
    }
    .....
}
```

The function does not detect the $pic parameter if I request an URL like this:

http://dev.hobbyathletes.com/tri/Ocean-Lava-Lancerote-Triathlon-2014/photos/gallery/6

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: in your url, you can find the `$pic` in `$tab` var. you can not combine all these routes to one method.

Comment: yup that is correct, thanks. I did now as I commented on the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is right :

```
Route::get('tri/{uniquename}/{photos}/{gallery}/{pic}',  array( 'as' => 'sportevent', 'uses' =>  'SporteventController@thisevent'));
```

in your code the Laravel think you have two arguments and $tab argument will be as $pic

Comment: Thanks, that is kind of not incorrect, but that doesn't solve my problem... I did my route now as `'tri/{uniquename}/{tab?}/{filter?}/{pic?}/'` and cought the exception with `/photos/gallery/` in my function